# Obsession with the rich and famous

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Either a word or brief phrase describing the fixation on the part of ordinary people and the media on a small segment of society living an extravagant lifestyle.

Example sentences:

- What's behind America's [obsession with the rich and famous]?
- A left-wing blogger called out the New York Times for its [glorification of the .0001%] in its lifestyle columns.

Related questions:

- [What do you call a person who craves fame and fortune?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142289/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-craves-fame-and-fortune)
- [Word for people who buy things because they are more expensive/ for the brand](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51357/word-for-people-who-buy-things-because-they-are-more-expensive-for-the-brand)

These do not answer my question because I am interested in a word describing the way the media lavishes attention on the lifestyles of people who are wealthy but not otherwise newsworthy.

Comment: "Celebrity worship" doesn't quite get there, right? It doesn't speak to the vacuous exclusively wealth-based nature of their celebrity. Maybe something like: "the media's bootlicking fixation with the asinine antics of the underachieving hyper-rich" ...though that's probably not succinct enough!

Comment: I believe it is [elitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitism). The phrase "elitist media" is used also.

Comment: An interesting aspect of this is why the rest of the world is star-struck by American celebrities and the British monarchy.

Answer (score 1):

One psychological term is **celebrity worship syndrome**, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celebrity_worship_syndrome) "an obsessive addictive disorder in which a person becomes overly involved with the details of a celebrity's personal and professional life."

Other common terms for an extreme interest in celebrities include **fandom** and **celebrity obsession** - [Collins dictionary defines "fandom"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fandom); [Healthline article](https://www.healthline.com/health/parenting/child-fandoms); book [Celebrity and Entertainment Obsession](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Celebrity_and_Entertainment_Obsession/ObIFCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) by Michael S. Levy (Rowman & Littlefield, 2015). *Fandom* suggests obsession with a particular celebrity, but *celebrity obsession* is more general.

There are more informal terms; a [BBC article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/articles/zjgv6v4) uses the verbal noun **stanning**, defined as "to show strong appreciation towards a musician, Love Island star or even fictional character that you adore." This term comes from Eminem's song "Stan", about an obsessive fan.

Answer (score 0):

**Oligarchism** suggests the meaning sought, but if you are open to hyphenated-compounding qualifying under single-word criteria, **Oligarch-fixation** probably comes closer.

However, you may disagree, given your mention of people who are wealthy but not otherwise newsworthy.  Some would say the the existence, and arguably the disproportionate influence, of a billionaire class, is newsworthy in itself.

Comment: I think OP is talking about Kardashians-like people here, whom cannot be called an oligarchy, since they are not in power.

Answer (score 0):

**Starstruck / star-struck** (adj.)

As an adjective, *starstruck* needs to be paired with a noun; however, I think it captures your meaning:

> What's behind America's obsessively **starstruck** society?

> A left-wing blogger called out the New York Times for its its
> **starstruck** lifestyle columns.

---

> Fascinated by famous people, especially those connected with the
> entertainment industry; overwhelmed or greatly impressed by the
> presence of a celebrity. OED

> Particularly taken with celebrities (such as movie stars) [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/starstruck)

> *Often disapproving.* Feeling great or too much respect for famous or important people, especially famous actors or performers.
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/star-struck)

---

> Society is simultaneously envious of and curious about anyone who gets
> rich and famous, even at one remove. Thus, being the proud albeit
> unemployed father of a tennis prodigy is not only legitimate but it's
> a ticket to minor celebrity. And within the closed society of tennis, **starstruck**
> functionaries, cynical agents, and even the conscientious
> damage-control specialists who really do have the best interest of the
> kids at heart treat tennis father with the deference due a pasha.
> [Peter Bodo; *The Courts of Babylon*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Courts_of_Babylon/JpwvAaZ5K1kC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=society%20is%20starstruck&pg=PT80&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> Given that we've become a society **starstruck** on itself, most of
> these self-important people are going to be quite disappointed in the
> long run. Journalist Chris Heath summarized the phenomenon perfectly:
> "I'm not sure that we aren't seeing the emergence of a society in
> which almost everyone who isn't famous considers themselves cruelly
> and unfairly unheard."
> [Eric Dezenhall; *Glass Jaw*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Glass_Jaw/w0F0AwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=society%20is%20starstruck&pg=PT57&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> For reasons such as those related above, the rich and famous have
> credibility for us **star-struck** Americans, beyond any we should
> rationally attribute to them as a consequence of their success in
> whatever is the domain in which they've achieved their prominence as
> larger-than-life characters in America's consciousness. As Tevye put
> it, right or wrong, "When you're rich they think you really know." And
> the potential credibility that accrues to celebrities is by no means
> independent of their physical attractiveness.
> [Robert Pellegrini;
> *Identities for Life and Death*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Identities_for_Life_and_Death/PMYF9D9rVWEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=we%20are%20starstruck%20by%20the%20rich%20and%20famous&pg=PA125&printsec=frontcover) (2010)